# How to order strings inside a Select box in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a select box that will return my list of projects in alphabetic order:

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, current_user.projects.all(:order => 'name').collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}) %>
```

This works as long as the name field contains only one word, e.g. **Project**.

All entries containing blanks, e.g. **My project**, will not be ordered though. They simply appear at the top of the list.

How can I order *all* of the strings?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is what I ended up with:

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, current_user.projects.all(:order => 'name').sort_by{|n| n.name.downcase}.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}) %>
```

Seems like the uppercase entries were causing the problem. The *sort_by* method comes to the rescue. Not sure if there's a better way to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try sort function

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, current_user.projects.all(:order => 'name').collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}.sort) %>
```

This will sort your list.

Use it in this manner

```
<%= f.select :brand_id, options_for_select(current_user.projects.all(:order => 'name').collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ]}.sort), {}, :id => 'dealerships_filter_brand_id' %>
```

Please try this, i've used it and it worked for me.

Comment: No, I don't get any error at all. The result is just the same as without ".sort" at the end.

Comment: I've tried in my console this:  a = [["Nissan", 1], ["Infiniti", 2]];  a.sort and it gives output  [["Infiniti", 2], ["Nissan", 1]]. i think same type of list is generated for you, which should work

Comment: Yes, it works. But what happens when those entries contain blank spaces? They won't get sorted on my end.

Comment: i can't get you. can you explain properly?

Comment: but it will work with blank spaces, if this is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort method on array for this, As your code contains array of pairs [name, id], 
you can sort this like,

arr.sort! { |a, b| a.first <=> b.first }

Considering you want to sort using first arg name

even better to use if have to sort on first argument

arr.sort!

Comment: Using `sort_by(&:first)` is probably a better idea.

Comment: to use first argument to sort even no need of block

Comment: That's true as well. You should adjust your answer.